# How to change value into date format and How to change value into time format

Tags: python, date, data-conversion

I have two columns one with values that represents time and another with values that represent a date (both values are in floating type), I have the following data in each column:

```
df['Time'] 
540.0 
630.0
915.0
1730.0
2245.0 

df['Date']
14202.0
14202.0
14203.0
14203.0
```

I need to create new columns with the correct data format for these two columns, to be able to analyze data with date and time in distinct columns.

For `['Time']` I need to convert the format to:

```
 540.0  =  5h40 OR TO  5.40 am
2245.0  = 22h45 OR TO 10.45 pm
```

For `['Date']`, I need to convert the format to:
Each number we can say that represent "days":
where 0 ("days") = 01-01-1980

So if I add 01-01-1980 to 14202.0 = 18-11-1938

and if I add: 01-01-1980 + 14203.0 = 19-11-1938,

**this way is possible to do with excel but I need a way to do in Python.**

I tried different types of code but nothing works, for example, one of the codes that I tried was the one below:

```
# creating a variable with the data in column ['Date'] adding the days into the date:

Time1 = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

# When I print it is possible to see that 14203 in row n.55384 is added at the end of the date created but including time, and is not what I want:

print(Time1.loc[[55384]])
55384   1970-01-01 00:00:00.000014203
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

# printing the same row (55384) to check the value 14203.0, that was added above:

print(df["Date"].loc[[55384]])
55384    14203.0
Name: Date, dtype: float64
```

For `['Time']` I have the same problem I can't have time without a date, I also tried to insert ':', but is not working even converting the data type to string.

I hope that someone can help me with this matter, and any doubt please let me know, sometimes is not easy to explain.

Comment: Reformat the question, this is painful too look at.  Just use one block for all your code and describe your problem.

Comment: Hi @ilamaaa, please have a look and see if Is better this way or if is better to divide into two different questions?

Comment: Looks likes excels date and time formats which I am no expert in, is it viable to use pandas read_excel when grabbing the data initially.

Comment: I just gave an example of how to solve the problem with Excel, to demostrate what output I need from Python

Comment: First I import the Excel file into Microsoft SQL server because is a big file to work directly from Excel. I am using 'df = pd.read_sql_query' to read the data from Sql server. The only problem is to find a code that can do what I need from date and time.

Comment: have you tried reading the excel file directly with ```pandas.read_excel()``` as per my earlier suggestion, it seems like it handles dates pretty well.

Comment: doesn't work because my file is in SQL server, so I just can read if I use: 'pd.read_sql_query()' , if I still can use 'pandas.read_excel()' please let me know how.

Comment: You're saying 
"and if I add: 01-01-1980 + 14203.0 = 19-11-1938,"
How does that work, are you goint back from 1980 to 1938? Is the difference a negative offset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solving problems with Date

`from datetime import datetime`

`from datetime import timedelta`

`startdate_string = "1980/01/01"` #defining start date in string format

`startdate_object = datetime.strptime(startdate_string, "%Y/%m/%d").date()` # changing string format date, to date object using strptime function

`startdate_object` # print startdate_object to check date

## creating a list to add in the dataframe a new column with date format

`import math`
`datenew = []`

`dates = df['UTS_Date']` # data from the original column 'UTS_Date'

`for values in dates:` # using an if statement to accept null values and appending them into the new list

`if math.isnan(values):`

```
    `datenew.append('NaN')`

    `continue `

`currentdate1 = startdate_object + timedelta(days= float(values))` # add the reference data (startdate_object) to a delta (which is the value in each row of the column)
`datenew.append(str(currentdate1)) ` # converte data into string format and add in the end of the list, removing any word from the list (such: datetime.date)
```

`print (len(datenew))` # check the length of the new list datenew, to ensure that all rows on the data are in the new list

`df.insert(3, 'Date', datenew)` #creating a new column in data frame for date format

Answer (score 0):

regarding the time conversion:

```
# change to integer
tt= [int(i) for i in df['Time']]
# convert to time
time_ = pd.to_datetime(tt,format='%H%M').time
# convert from 24 hour, to 12 hour time format
[t.strftime("%I:%M %p") for t in time_]
```

Comment: I just put the answer for date and time. Was complicated to solve but now it works. The problem was that was not accepting the time or data format because was not in the correct format that Python normally accepts, that was my problem but is solved now thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

## solving problems with Time

`timenew = []` # creating a new list

`times = df['Time']` # variable times is equal to the column df['Time'] of the dataframe

## variable to find the location of time that is >= 2400

`i = 0`

`def Normalize_time (val):`

```
`offset = 0`
`if val >= 2400:`
    `offset = 1 ` 
# converting val into integer, to remove decimal places
hours = int(val / 100)
# remove hours and remain just with minutes
minutes = int(val) - hours * 100 
# to convert every rows above 24h
hours = (hours%23) - offset 
# zfill recognizes that it must have two characters (in this case) for hours and minutes 
# and if there aren't enough characters,
# it will add by padding zeros on the left until reaching the number of characters in the argument
return str(hours).zfill(2) + ':' + str(minutes).zfill(2)
```

## creating a for statement to add all the values in the new list, using 'function Normalize_time()'

`for values in times:`
    # using an if statement to accept null values and appending them into the new list
    `if math.isnan(values):`

```
    `timenew.append('NaN')  `
   ` continue `
# using values into the function 'Normalize_time()'
timestr = Normalize_time(values)
# appending each value in the new list
timenew.append(timestr)
```

`print(len(timenew))` # check the length of new list timenew, to ensure that all rows on the data are in the new list

`df.insert(4, 'ODTime', timenew)` #creating a new column in data frame